# Connection Between Two Lexicographic Rules in Simplex Method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

In my study of the simplex method, I have come across two formulations of the lexicographic pivoting rule. Currently I am having trouble understanding how they are connected to each other.

1. In Section 3.4 of [*Introduction to Linear Optimization* by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis](http://athenasc.com/linoptbook.html), the lexicographic rule is applied to the simplex tableau $B^{-1}[b\mid A]$ of the standard form problem
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \min&\quad c^\top x \\
   \text{s.t.}&\quad Ax=b \\
   &\quad x\ge 0.
   \end{align}
   $$
2. Exercises 3.15 and 3.16 of the book present a second formulation of the lexicographic rule, which works on $B^{-1}[b\mid I]$. This approach is equivalent to solving the $\epsilon$-perturbed problem. The same formulation is also used in [Chvátal's *Linear Programming*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Programming.html?id=DN20_tW_BV0C) and [Vanderbei's *Linear Programming*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-7630-6).

**My question:** How are the two formulations connected?

**My understanding:** In the proofs of the finite termination of the simplex method with lexicographical rule, a crucial assumption is that the initial basis matrix $B$ satisfies that all rows of $B^{-1}[b\mid A]$ or $B^{-1}[b\mid I]$ are lexicographically positive. Under this assumption, the proofs of the finite termination have the same spirit, namely, (1) the rows' lexicographical positiveness is maintained in each iteration, and (2) a special quantity that is determined completely by the basis strictly increases lexicographically, hence each basis is visited at most once.

While this assumption does not hold in general, [Chvátal's book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_Programming.html?id=DN20_tW_BV0C) and [Vanderbei's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-7630-6) get around this by working with a sepcial form
$$
\min\quad c^\top x\quad
\text{s.t.}\quad Ax\le b,\quad x\ge0
$$
with $b\ge0$. Then by adding the slack variables $s$ which gives
$$
\min\quad c^\top x\quad
\text{s.t.}\quad Ax+s=b,\quad x,s\ge0,
$$
and by choosing $s$ to be the basic variables, we have a very easy initial basis matrix, namely, $B=I$ which has all rows lexicographically positive. In contrast, [Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis' book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-7630-6) uses a different approach: by reordering the variables, we can always assume that the first $m$ columns of $B^{-1}A$ form the identity matrix, so every row of $B^{-1}[b\mid A]$ is lexicographically positive.

Is my understanding correct? Any other insights would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the special case where we turn $Ax \le b$ into $Ax + s = b$, there are two equivalent formulations of the lexicographic pivoting rule.

1. Change $b$ to $b+\epsilon$, where $1 \gg \epsilon_1 \gg \epsilon_2 \gg \dots \gg \epsilon_m > 0$.
2. Make sure that the columns of the slack variables are first in our matrix: in equational form, we have $$[I \mid A] \begin{bmatrix}s \\ x\end{bmatrix} = b.$$ Then, only allow bases $B$ such that $B^{-1}[b \mid I \mid A]$ is lexicographically positive: in each row, the first nonzero entry is positive.

These are equivalent, because in $B^{-1}[b \mid I \mid A]$, the first $m+1$ entries of each row are exactly the coefficients of $1, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \dots, \epsilon_m$ in $B^{-1}(b+\epsilon)$.

Note that we will never need to look beyond the first $m+1$ entries, because they cannot all be $0$: that could only happen if $B^{-1}I$ had an all-zero row, but that would make it singular, even though it has inverse $B$. So a rule that talks about lexicographic positivity of $B^{-1}[b \mid I]$ is equivalent to a rule that references the entire matrix $B^{-1}[b \mid I \mid A]$.

---

The same relationship holds more subtly when working with $Ax=b$, except here, we have to wait until we've found a starting feasible basis. Suppose we start the simplex method in basis $B_1$, where $(B_1)^{-1}b \ge 0$. Then the following two strategies are equivalent:

1. Change $(B_1)^{-1}b$ to $(B_1)^{-1}b+\epsilon$, where $1 \gg \epsilon_1 \gg \epsilon_2 \gg \dots \gg \epsilon_m > 0$. (Or in other words, perturb the original system $Ax=b$ to $Ax = b + B_1 \epsilon$.)
2. Reorder the columns of $A$ to put $B_1$ first: $A = [B_1 \mid N_1]$. Then, only allow bases $B$ such that the rows of $B^{-1}[b \mid A]$ are lexicographically positive. Note that this holds for $B = B_1$.

These are equivalent, because in $B^{-1}[b \mid A]$, the first $m+1$ entries of each row are the rows of $B^{-1}[b \mid B_1]$, which are exactly the coefficients of $1, \epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_m$ in $B^{-1}(b + B_1 \epsilon)$.

Note that we will, again, never need to look beyond the first $m+1$ entries: that could only happen if $B^{-1}B_1$ had an all-zero row, which would make it singular, but it has an inverse $(B_1)^{-1}B$.

---

I do not see a justification for lexicographic pivoting in the following form: take a system $Ax=b$ with its columns in whatever order we got them in, and only allow bases $B$ such that the rows of $B^{-1}[b \mid A]$ are lexicographically positive.

(It's possible that it works, but in my mind only the perturbation method has an intuitive justification for why it works, and the lexicographic positivity method is justified by being equivalent to the perturbation method. However, that equivalence only holds if we're careful about the column ordering, as above.)

However, this is not an issue, since we can never even get started with the simplex method unless we have an initial feasible basis $B_1$ to use.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point. When working with the standard form $Ax=b$, $x\ge0$, isn't the lexicographic rule applied to $B^{-1}[b\mid A]$ (that is, the whole matrix $A$) instead of the $m$ basic columns?

Comment: You *can* apply it to the whole matrix $A$. However, if the first $m$ columns you look at are the columns that were basic in the initial feasible basis, then you will never have to look at the other columns. (The lexicographic positivity condition is that the first nonzero entry is positive, and the first nonzero entry will always be in one of the first $m$ columns.)

Comment: But I guess in the subsequent iterations the first $m$ columns are no longer all of the basic columns, so we need to look at the whole matrix $A$?

Comment: If the first $m$ columns were the basic columns once, then they will *always* be linearly independent, which guarantees we'll never need to look at the other columns.

Comment: I have edited my answer to better match your notation, so I hope that it makes more sense to you now; let me know if you still have questions!

Comment: Thanks! You are amazing!